# Is there any way to compute a static P value in a polynomial equation?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Assume that we have a second order polynomial equation.

$$0 = P\times 2z^2 + P\times 3z - 3 + z + z^2$$

And $z \in ℂ$ plane. But $|z| = 1$. Then I want to determine $P$ when $|z| = 1$.
Assume that we are on the dotted grey line, but we don't know where. We know that the absolute value where we are is $|z| = 1$.

My question is: How can I find $P$? If I was on $z = -1 +0i$, then it was easy. But I don't know $real(z)$ and $imag(z)$. Notice that $P > 0$.

[image]

Comment: Is this polynomial intended to be $(2P+1)z^2 + (3P+1)z - 3$? Is $P3$ meant to be something like $P_3$?

Comment: Sorry. $P3$ is $P\times 3$

Comment: What to you mean by *static* ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not going to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $p\in \mathbb{R}$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$, with $|z|=1$, are such that
$$(2p+1)z^2 + (3p+1)z - 3 = 0$$

If $p=-{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, the equation reduces to $-{\large{\frac{z}{2}}}-3=0$,
which yields $z=-6$, contrary to $|z|=1$.

Hence $p\ne-{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, so the equation is quadratic in $z$.

Consider cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;z$ is real.

Then $|z|=1$ implies $z = \pm 1$.

If $z=1$, the equation reduces to $5p -1=0$, which yields $p={\large{\frac{1}{5}}}$.

If $z=-1$, the equation reduces to $-p - 5=0$, which yields $p=-5$.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;z$ is non-real.

Since the coefficients of the quadratic are real, it follows that the roots, $z_1,z_2$ say, are complex conjugates, hence $z_1z_2=1$.

But by Vieta's formulas, $z_1z_2 = {\large{\frac{-3}{2p+1}}}$, hence $1=  {\large{\frac{-3}{2p+1}}}$, which yields $p=-2$.

Thus, considering all cases, the possible values of $p$ are $-5,-2,{\large{\frac{1}{5}}}$.

Comment: Well done! Is it not possible to do a numerical solution to this? For example. Try different $P$ all the time, from 0 to...for example 100. >> P = 4
P =  4
>> A = [P*4 P*3 2 5]
A =

   16   12    2    5

>> roots(A)
ans =

  -0.95928 + 0.00000i
   0.10464 + 0.56108i
   0.10464 - 0.56108i

>>

Comment: @Daniel Mårtensson: I don't understand what you're asking. For the given equation, assuming $p$ is real, there are only $3$ possible values of $p$, namely, $p=-5,\;p=-2,\;p={\large{\frac{1}{5}}}$. So you can't just take arbitrary values of $p$. Are you asking about a different equation?

Answer (score 0):

From the equation,

$$P=-\frac{z^2+z-3}{2z^2+3z}$$ and we can set $z=e^{i\theta}$ to enforce the constraint $|z|=1$. Now, express that the imaginary part of

$$P=-\frac{e^{i2\theta}+e^{i\theta}-3}{2e^{i2\theta}+3e^{i\theta}}$$ is zero, while the real part is positive.